# Calling method in separate Class- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my main.dart at the end of a method I call 2 entities, one is within main.dart and works fine, the other is in another Class, `_mapItemsExample2`.

I have implemented `_MyAppState(this._mapItemsExample2);` functionality to call it as widget.

```
void main() {  
  SdkContext.init(IsolateOrigin.main);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'DMSans'),
    home: MyApp(), 
   ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MapItemsExample2? _mapItemsExample2;
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState(this._mapItemsExample2);
} 

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final MapItemsExample2? _mapItemsExample2;
  _MyAppState(this._mapItemsExample2);


            Future<void> intermodalRouter() async{
       ...

       _sendIntermodalDataToSecondScreen(context, mappedValues, dest);       //works fine
       widget._mapItemsExample2?.showFirstPolylineMapMarkers(deplat, deplong, deplocname);


      }
    });
  }
```

It will pass data to

```
class MapItemsExample2 {

  void showFirstPolylineMapMarkers(deplat, deplong, deplocname) async {
    print('showFirst');
...
```

But it goes dead and doesn't print or call `_showFirstPolylineMapMarkers`

I need to call the method to trigger a display of data. No errors showing but even after adding the widget function as suggested it displays nothing and doesnt `print` readouts

Any guidance appreciated

Thank you

**Update**

Recieving error in main.dart

```
2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
```

on

```
final MapItemsExample2 _mapItemsExample2 = MapItemsExample2();
```

```
class MapItemsExample2 {


  MapItemsExample2(ShowDialogFunction2 showDialogCallback2, HereMapController hereMapController)
      : _showDialog2 = showDialogCallback2,
        _hereMapController = hereMapController {

  void showFirstPolylineMapMarkers(deplat, deplong, deplocname) async {
    print('showFirst');
```

Have tried adding parameters in but they are not recognised

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `?.` null-aware operator when calling `showFirstPolylineMapMarkers(..)`, so it will only call it if `widget._mapItemsExample2` is not null. Have you checked whether it is null or not at the time you're making this call?

In your code it is apparent that no instance of `_mapItemsExample2` is being passed into `MyApp()` when you call it from `main()`, since the parameter list is empty. You need to create an instance of it and pass it into MyApp, or get access to a previously created instance to pass in. I don't have enough code to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: When I hover over it does not say null and displays ```MapItemsExample2? _mapItemsExample2```, which is the link to the other Class

Comment: It can be null at runtime, the hover just tells you the type, which is a nullable MapItemsExample2 object. The most basic check you can do is `if (widget._mapItemsExample2 != null) {  widget._mapItemsExample2?.showFirstPolylineMapMarkers(deplat, deplong, deplocname); } else { print('_mapItems was null!') }` and run your code again to see.

Comment: Okay thanks. Have ran and is returning null. I thought I had the Class linked fine, it doesn't show errors and on hover displays that it links to ```_mapItemsExample2``` from main.dart. What could it be? Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer with where the error is coming from. Can you please accept it?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am new to Flutter so don't fully undertstand, is ```final MapItemsExample2? _mapItemsExample2;
  _MyAppState(this._mapItemsExample2);```  not creating an instance? Thanks

Comment: Nope, you need to call the constructor for the object and assign it to the variable. Create one my modifying the first snippet to `final MapItemsExample2 _mapItemsExample2 = MapItemsExample2()`. I'm not sure if the constructor requires any parameters. I recommend doing a Dart tutorial to get familiar with the language.

Comment: Thanks, have added and get ```2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.``` Have updated code with some more context

Comment: This is a very basic error that has nothing to do with Flutter, but shows that you have some gaps in your understanding of object oriented programming and me answering this question won't help you solve all your problems. Please seek out a Dart beginners course or an introduction to OOP course online.